# Symfony 2.8 An exception ocurred in driver SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused Error

Tags: sqlite, symfony

I want to use sqlite in my app but when I execute the command to create the database I have this error

> An exception ocurred in driver SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection
>   refused

Command:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

parameters.yml file:

```
   parameters:
   database_host:      localhost
   database_name:      trivago
   database_user:      root
   database_password:  password
   database_path:      "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
```

config.yml file:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_sqlite
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your databases driver:
    #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
    #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
    #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
    #   3. Uncomment next line:
    path:     "%database_path%"
```

database_path in parameters.yml.dist is already uncommented.

If I use the mysql driver it creates the database correctly.

Comment: Check that `database_user` and `database_password` are correct. You can try to connect directly to phpMyAdmin to make sure that everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

`Connection refused` most of the time means that your credentials are wrong or even the host. Check your parameters.yml and try to connect to your db directly with `sqlite3`